# Can c++ do this java builder pattern?

Tags: java, c++

In java it is possible for a builders setter methods to return the builder itself so that the invocations can be chained, like so:

```
public class builder{

private String name;
private int age;
private char glyph;

    public builder setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public builder setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }

public builder setGlyph(char glyph){
    this.glyph = glyph;
    return this;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    builder b = new builder().setName("").setAge(10).setGlyph('%');
}
}
```

Is this possible in c++?

Comment: you could use a constuctor with these 3 arguments

Comment: Your `setGlyph` method has `builder` as its declared return type, but does not return. Is that intensional?

Comment: If it is possible in Java, it _must_ be possible in C++. It must also be possible in Assembler :-)!

Comment: No that was uninetentional :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, sure, you can just return a reference to the builder:

```
Builder & setSomething(const std::string & smth) 
{
    // do setting
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I never knew there was a this keyword in c++!

Comment: @user2103959 Just remember that `this` is a pointer and has to be dereferenced `*` to get the `builder` object itself.

Comment: Very noobish question i think, but what is the need for the & before method header?

Comment: @user2103959: This is reference, like a constant pointer to the variable. Read more about references [here](http://cplus.about.com/od/learning1/ss/references.htm)

Comment: @user2103959 It means you're returning a **reference** to a `Builder`. Without it, you'd be returning a **copy**.

Comment: @user2103959 Look up [references](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html). It means the object returned is precisely the object denoted by `*this`, rather than a copy of that object.

Comment: So it is actually applying to what the method is returning?

Comment: @user2103959: Of course. This is a method declaration: method setSomething returns reference to a Builder.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, function chaining is certainly possible. The implementation of `setName` for example would look like:

```
builder& setName(std::string name)
{
  this->name = name;
  return *this;
}
```

It returns a reference to the object pointer to by `this`, which is of course the current object.