# Is there an alternative to the builder pattern that is preferred in C++?

Tags: java, c++, idioms, builder-pattern

I'm coming from Java where the builder pattern is used heavily, *e.g.*

```
Foo foo = new FooBuilder()
    .setBar(43)
    .setBaz("hello, world!")
    .enableCache(true)
    .build();
```

Automapper for example is popular library that generates this pattern via Java annotations.

I don't see any such library for C++—only gists and blog posts online with example ad hoc implementations.

Does the lack of a library imply that the builder pattern is not preferred in C++? What is the alternative or preferred idiom then?

Maybe it helps to describe what I actually want. I like the grammar that the builder pattern affords me, for example if there are 20 fields I could set (*e.g.* a large configuration),  but may only set 4 or may set all 20, without having to create explicit constructors for each case.

Comment: The "built-in" feature for this in C++ is [Designated Intiializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers).  You could self implement the builder pattern, but IIRC it doesn't map 100% into C++.

Comment: Not knowing anything about it and almost nothing about Java, but just reading some of https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html, its functionality seems far outside of what the C++ core language allows. There is no reflection that would make it possible for a library to inspect names of members/types and act based on that.

Comment: Ah @user17732522, my bad. I just meant to give a specific example I use in Java. I don't really need most of the features of AutoMapper. Just looking for a library that enables similar grammar.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381832 but since there's already a more up to date answer posted here, this might as well be the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern is aggregate initialisation:

```
Foo foo = {
    .bar=43,
    .baz="hello, world!",
    .enableCache=true,
};
```

Note that designated initialisers such as used here were introduced in C++20. Prior to that, you could only initialise sub objects positionally.

Another pattern, common in absence of designated initialisers, is value initialisation followed by assignment of data members:

```
Foo foo = {};
foo.bar = 43;
foo.baz = "hello, world!";
foo.enableCache = true;
```

Usage of neither pattern requires the use of a library.

Comment: I would mention that the first pattern requires that _all designators used in the expression must appear in the same order as the data members of_ the type being initialized, which is not the case if there's a builder pattern in place. Whether this is a big deal (and for me it's not) is another story.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your code, you can approximate it by having your settings return *this as follows:

```
class Foo {
public:
     Foo & setter1(int value) { ...; return *this; }
     Foo & setter2(int value) { ...; return *this; }
};

Foo foo;
foo.setter1(1)
   .setter2(2);
```

Or pointers or smart pointers, or whatever. I've taken to doing this because it makes for slightly cleaner code. Clearly, if your constructor does a lot, you're still doing a lot. You also have a problem if Foo is a subclass, and some of your setter calls are on the base class, because suddenly you don't have a Foo being returned, but a BaseFoo.

So it's not perfect.

I've seen self-implemented builder patterns that actually are a proper builder, but frankly, I think that's a lot of overhead with zero gain.

Answer (score -5):

You just have to fix the type error:

```
Foo foo = (*new FooBuilder())
    .setBar(43)
    .setBaz("hello, world!")
    .enableCache(true)
    .build();
```

The rest is defining your functions propertly to always return a FooBuilder& (except build returns a Foo).

That's assuming FooBuilder is something that accumulates options from various sources and doesn't just assign member variables. If your code is really like your example where you create the builder, assign all the options and build the Foo then just use a constructor or aggregate initialization:

```
Foo foo = {
    .bar=43,
    .baz="hello, world!",
    .enableCache=true,
};
```

Update: Here is the use case I had in mind when retaining the `new`:

```
FooBuilder *builer = nullptr;
if (use_bla_builder) {
    builder = new Bla::FooBuilder();
} else {
    builder = new Blub::FooBuilder();
}
Foo foo = (*builder)
    .setBar(43)
    .setBaz("hello, world!")
    .enableCache(true)
    .build();
delete builder;
```

Note: The builder is abstract while the Foo it builds is concrete.

Comment: `*new FooBuilder()` -> instaleak.

Comment: What typo? That example is in java.

Comment: @user4581301 True, you would never use this as such a 1 line example where you can't free the builder.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca -- the answer says "type **error**",  not "typo"; with the change that the answer gives, the code could be valid C++.

Comment: @PeteBecker my point is there's no error to fix in the question, they're just showing java code and asking how to implement that same pattern in C++

Comment: And to make it C++ code you take the code verbatim and fix the type error. The pattern is the same in C++ if you want to use it.

Comment: Why do you suggest adding `*` to fix the type error instead removing the `new`?  Doing the later would remove the memory leak that your version will cause.

Comment: If `build` returns a subtype then you need `Foo *foo`.

Comment: @NathanOliver also a possibility

Comment: re: *"also a possibility"* - how about showing just the possibilities that incur no bugs, instead of digging one's hills in? SO is about collecting *high quality* solutions, not just "possible" ones.